# What is the last level in Spice Bandits and where in the map is it?

Tags: spice-bandits

I have played factory backyard, but then I had to stop playing. When I came back I could  not tell what level was next. It says that the location progress was 98%, so I'm pretty sure that there is only one level left... can somebody tell me what is it and where to find it?

Answer (score 2):

Madagascar is the correct answer, however it's EAST of Africa

Comment: Still nothing maybe it did not come out of the map yet. Please tell me what level it besides. If it is not there, it has not come out yet. Is factory backyard the second to the last level?

Answer (score 0):

It's in Madagascar, just west of Africa.

Comment: Please be specific still cant see it. Or show a screenshot if where. Even my father who is a PRO in the game cant find it

Comment: Maybe it doesnt come out of the map yet...... BAD LUCK FOR ME!! :((((((((

Comment: Thanks men!!!!! I finally got it!! It is in the island in WEST of africa LOL. Bad news is it is not in the map yet!!! GRRRRR!! Stupid glitches! Can anyone tell me how to make the level appear?